# R Studio installing stringi fails

Tags: r, stringi

I'm trying to invoke `knit` which tells me that it needs an updated version of `rmarkdown` which needs the package `stringi`.

When installing `stringi` I get the following error:

```
> install.packages("stringi")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/matan/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
stringi  1.1.5  1.1.6              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/stringi_1.1.5.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/stringi_1.1.5.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/stringi_1.1.5.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘stringi’ failed
```

How can I fix this so I can finally `knit` my `.RMD` in peace?

**Edit (Solution)**:

1. Download windows binary (r-release: stringi_1.1.6.zip) from `https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html`
2. Install by `> install.packages(".../Downloads/stringi_1.1.6.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simplest solution is download *.zip* or *.tar.gz* file from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html) and install it choosing in RStudio *Tool* -> *Install packages...*, change *Install from:* to *Package Archive File* and choose your downloaded file.

Comment: Worked for me. I was trying to install it on R 3.4.3, none of the other methods worked. Installed `stringi` 1.1.6